# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch in matlab with swich case

Tags: matlab

I have a table from which I extract the largest element in each column defendant and his place in the table.

`Max = max(ARRAY,[],1);
    for i=1:1 
    for j=1:30
        [X,Y] = find(ARRAY == Max(i,j));
        Locations(i,j)=X;
     end
     end`

I want to get a table `Sample_Targets (i, j) 10 * 30` where depending on the value of (Locations (i, j)) from (1-10) to store in each column is a variable of `type A = [1;0;0;0;0; 0;0;0;0;0];`

```
  for i=1:1 
for j=1:30
    switch  Locations(i,j)
            case {1}
                Sample_Targets(i,j) = [1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0];
            case {2}
                Sample_Targets(i,j) = [0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0];
            case {3}
                Sample_Targets(i,j)  = [0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0];
            case {4}
                Sample_Targets(i,j)  = [0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0];
            case {5}
                Sample_Targets(i,j)  = [0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0];
            case {6}
                Sample_Targets(i,j)  = [0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0];
            case {7}
                Sample_Targets(i,j)  = [0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0];
            case {8}
                Sample_Targets(i,j)  = [0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0];
            case {9}
                Sample_Targets(i,j)  = [0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0];
            case {10}
                Sample_Targets(i,j)  = [0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1];
         end    
    end
  end
```

Every time I get the same error:

Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

What can I do?

Comment: Please provide code which allows to reproduce your problem, including initialisation of all variables.

Comment: This is all my friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either your Sample_Targets variable needs to be of the cell type, or, alternatively, a 3D array.

- Cell: Use {} for cell subscripts, i.e. Sample_Targets{i,j}
- 3D array: Use  Sample_Targets(i,j,:) = [ .... ];

Note, the latter is only possible because in your switch statement you always assign an array with the same size. If that would not be the case, option a) is the only possible.